# Javascript полнотекстовой поиск

Tags: javascript, search

Есть строка StringAnyText. Есть ли плагин или скрипт, который бы при вводе в инпут не менее 3 символов искал бы в этой строке и подсвечивал. Например str,any,ext в StringAnyText были бы найдены.

Comment: а где сказано что искать надо в массиве ?

Comment: Как вариант, если возможно использование jquery, то вот с поиском в массиве
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/